# How do I overlay points/polygons in a 3D map using QGIS2threejs?

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis2threejs

I am trying to produce a topographical map of an area, but I need my points to sit on top of it. I have created the actual 3d rendering in QGIS2threejs, and I can see the option to include points, but they appear underneath the 3d rendering, even though they do have height data!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that:
qgis2threejs:
layer - layer properties

1. z-coordinate - mode: choose your dem
2. style - height: if you have a column with height values, you can choose this column

If the symbols have now not the right height, you can do than (example multiplicate with 2):
height*2  (in the field "height" (see above point 2))